# Sufficient Condition for the Differentiability of Multivariable Functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

**Theroem** (A Sufficient Condition for the Differentiability of Multivariable Functions)

Let  $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ be an open set, $a\in A$, and $f:A\subset \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$. If all the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}, i = 1,..., n $,   exist in a neighbourhood of $a$ and they are continuous in $a$, then $f$ is differentiable in $a$.

**Proof**

Let $h\in \mathbb R^n$ such that $a-h\in A, a+h\in A$.
$$\begin{align*}
f (a+h)-f(a)&= f(a_1+h_1, ... , a_n+h_n)-f(a_1,...,a_n)\\
&=f(a_1+h_1, a_2+h_2,... , a_n+h_n)-f(a_1,a_2+h_2,... , a_n+h_n)\\
&+f(a_1,a_2+h_2,a_3+h_3,... , a_n+h_n)-f(a_1,a_2, a_3+h_3,... , a_n+h_n)  \\& +...+f(a_1, ..., a_{n-1}, a_n+h_n)-f(a_1,..., a_{n-1},a_n)
\end{align*}$$

The functions $g_i:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined $\forall i \in \{1,...,n\}$ as $$g_i(x)=f(a_1,...,a_{i-1}, x, a_{i+1}+h_{i+1}, ..., a_n+h_n),$$

are single-variable functions. Because of our hypothesis, these functions are  continuous and diferentiable in a neighbourhood of $a_i, \forall i \in \{i,...,n\}$. Hence, using the Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem, we have that $\forall i \in \{i,...,n\}, \exists \xi_i \in (a_i, a_i+h_i) $

$$g_i(a_i+h_i)-g_i(a_i)=\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a_1,...,a_{i-1}, \xi_i, a_{i+1}+h_{i+1}, ..., a_n+h_n)h_i.$$

And hence, the previous telescoping sum  results in $$f(a+h)-f(a)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a_1,...,a_{i-1}, \xi_i, a_{i+1}+h_{i+1}, ..., a_n+h_n)h_i.$$

Therefore, $$\frac {\mid f(a+h)-f(a)-\begin {pmatrix} \frac {\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a)& ... &\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_n}(a) \end{pmatrix}\begin {pmatrix} 
 h_1\\...\\h_n\end{pmatrix}|}{||h||}=\\ |\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a_1,...,\xi_i, ..., a_n+h_n)-\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a_1,... ,a_n+h_n) \right) \frac {h_i}{||h||} | \underbrace{\leq}_\text{Triangle Inequality} \sum_{i=1}^n | \frac {\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a_1,...,\xi_i, ..., a_n+h_n)-\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a_1,... ,a_n+h_n) | \frac {|h_i|}{||h||} \underbrace{\leq}_{\frac {h_i} {||h||} \leq 1} \sum_{i=1}^n | \frac {\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a_1,...,\xi_i, ..., a_n+h_n)-\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a_1,... ,a_n+h_n) |$$

As de partial derivatives are continuous in $a$ and $\xi_i\in (a_i, a_i+h_i) \forall i$, each addend of the previous sum tends to $0 $ as $h \to 0$. Therefore, $$\lim _{h\to 0}\frac {|f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)(h)|}{||h||}=0 \Rightarrow \text{ f is differentiable in $a$.}$$

**Question** 
I know that this condition can be generalised:

**Theroem** Let $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ be an open set, $a\in A$, and $f:A\subset \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$. If at least one of the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} $,   exist in $a$ and the reaining $n-1$ partial derivatives exist in a neighbourhood of $a$ and they are continuous in $a$, then $f$ is differentiable in $a$.

**But I do not know how to prove this theorem, since I cannot use the Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem for each variable as I did in the previous proof. Is it possible to generalise this condition even more?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: HINT: Assume $i=1$ and start by proceeding from $a$ in the $x_1$ direction.

Comment: There's a proof in the second edition (1974) of *Mathematical Analysis* by Apostol, Theorem 12.11 on p. 357.